# Best practice in Xamarin Forms to perform a filter search

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to perform a filter search with dynamic fields and i am not sure about the best way to do this.

We have a lot of documents with different fields and would like these to be used like a filter search.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

[image: Example of what I am looking to do.]

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? I guess I don't understand what do you mean when you say "documents with different fields". Maybe I did had a similar scenario.

Comment: Not clear! Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MVVM pattern. Here are the steps:

- Declare `ObservableCollection<ItemType>` for each of the drop down lists in your ViewModel.
- Create `SelectedType1, SelectedType2` etc. properties for selected values corresponding to each drop down list.
- Attach SelectionChanged and TextChanged method handlers for each drop down lists in the view which updates the corresponding selection properties in the ViewModel.
- Delcare `ObservableCollection<SearchResultType> SearchResults` in the ViewModel which holds the search results for the given search.
- Declare `SearchCommand` property in the ViewModel which executes the `Search` method.
- Declare `Search` method which essentially makes a web request call or a local database search query depending on your requirement. This search method now has access to all the drop down selections/text typed by the user.
- Insert the results obtained in the search method into the `SearchResults` collection.
- Bind the `SearchResults` collection to the `ListView.ItemsSource` in the View.
- Bind the `SearchCommand` to the search action button (top right button in your view).

Happy coding!